# .bat on Mac OS X

Tags: windows, macos, batch-file

I am a Windows user. Due to the need to develop hybrid app for iOS, I have to use Mac OS. I have a tiny `bat` file that will ask a few simple questions and send the parameter to gulp to executes automation task.

My `bat` file looks something like this:

```
@echo off

choice /C:yn /n /m "Do you want to run JSHint? [Y/N]: "
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 (
    set answer=n
) else (
    set answer=y
)

echo Starting gulp...
gulp --jshint "%answer%"
```

How can I get my `bat` file to run on Mac? I know `bat` file is Windows thing. So, what is the Mac equivalent? Is there anyway I can directly convert it to Mac support?

Thank you.

Comment: You are basically looking to create a BASH script.  Here is a list of commands you can use. http://ss64.com/osx/

Comment: AppleScript? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html